# How to avoid user redirection to login page from other page after successful login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute

I have a login page and after user logs in, I want to redirect the user to a dashboard page.

I have 3 pages:

1. Dashboard: user will be redirected to this page after login
2. UserList
3. Statistics

Now what happens after user is login and redirected to this dashboard page and when I enter this below login url:

```
http://localhost:1927/
```

Route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then above url takes user to login page even if user is logged in because that is the root url of my web site.

But what I want is suppose user is on this page:

```
http://localhost:1927/UserList/Index
```

And if I enter below login url in my browser :

```
http://localhost:1927/
```

Then user should be redirected to this url:

```
http://localhost:1927/UserList/Index
```

This is my code:

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
          var d= HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
          ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
          return View();
    }
}

[UserAuthorize]
public class DashboardController : BaseController
{
}

[UserAuthorize]
public class UserListController : BaseController
{
}
```

Authorize attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class UserAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public UserAuthorize() { }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            bool authorized = false;

            /// MVC 4 boilerplate code follows
            if (filterContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

            bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                          || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

            if (skipAuthorization)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "MyAuthorizeAttribute cannot be used within a child action caching block."
                );
            }

            if (!AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
            if (httpContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

            // check to make sure the user is authenticated as my custom identity
            if ((httpContext.User.Identity == null) || !(httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
                return false;

            return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Login",
                controller = "Authentication",
                returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
            }));
    }
}
```

**Note**: I am using asp.net owin identity custom authentication and without authentication, user will not be allowed to view Dashboard, Userlist and Statistics page.

Comment: Change you default route to `defaults: new { controller = "UserList", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke :But when i will run my application then my first page will be login page and consider if i am at Statistics page and enter login url then??

Comment: You have an `[Authorize]` attribute on your other controller methods. If an unauthorized user tries to navigate to any of those methods, they will be automatically taken to the login page, and as soon as they login they will be taken back to the page they were trying to navigate to.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Ok i have changed my Default route to  controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" but still when user enter Authenticate/Login url in browser then login page gets open even after user is login

Comment: If the user wants to navigate to a page, then they should be able to (you cant prevent what they type in the address bar). You can always check if they are already authorized in the Login method and redirect them somewhere else if your want.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :So this is not possible that if user have open Statistics page after login and user open new tab and in this new tab enter login url then only option is to redirect user to any other page but not on the statistics page???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117212/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-learning).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117279/discussion-between-learning-and-stephen-muecke).